# Incrementing date object by hours/minutes in Groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy

I want to add hours or minutes to a current date. For example I create a Date object with current time and date, and I want to increment it by 30min, how can I do such thing in Grails/Groovy ?

> **Date Now** : Thu Jan 16 11:05:48 EST 2014
>   **Adding 30min to Now** : Thu Jan 16 11:35:48 EST 2014

I was wondering if I could do the same that we can do with add 1 to date and it moves it a day ahead.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046910/how-do-i-subtract-minutes-from-current-time

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use TimeCategory

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

currentDate =  new Date()

println currentDate

use( TimeCategory ) {
    after30Mins = currentDate + 30.minutes
}

println after30Mins
```

Comment: Link to the groovy API doc:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html

Comment: Gives out an exception like this: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hours for class: java.lang.Integer [See nested exception: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hours for class: java.lang.Integer]`

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is very simple, you can just manipulate the underlying millisecond value.

```
final Long HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000 // milliseconds in an hour
​Date now = new Date()
Date oneHourAgo = new Date(now.toInstant().toEpochMilli()​ - HOUR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `java.time` package.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

Date now = new Date()
Date thirtyMinsFromNow = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(30).toDate()

println "Date Now: $now"
println "Adding 30min to Now: $thirtyMinsFromNow"
```