# How to add n minutes in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am working in SoapUI , which supports GroovyScript in TestCases.
In some TestCases i supposed to use a date of now + 15 minutes, 30, or 90 minutes.
If im using this script:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

def tdFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
def today =  Calendar.getInstance()
def today15min = today.add(today.MINUTE,15)
def todayFormated = today15min.format(tdFormat)
```

gets NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method format() on null object error at line: 6.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166927/incrementing-date-object-by-hours-minutes-in-groovy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using TimeCategory.

```
use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
    println 15.minutes.from.now.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great and simple!   I'm modified it in script as `use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
   def newDate = 15.minutes.from.now.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' )
}` and result of this script is what i wanted to!

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` is a static class used to create `Date`s. [`Calendar.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) returns void, because it simply modifies the Calendar. You need to call [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) to get a `Date` object which you can then format how you please.