# Increment date to the next day using Groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, soapui, datetime-format

Trying to add 1 day to the simple date format.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
Date date = new Date();
def dateformat =  new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd")
def currentDate = dateformat.format(date)
log.info "Current Date : " + currentDate

Date date1 = (Date)dateformat.parse(currentDate);
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(date1); 
log info c1.add(Calendar.Date,1);
```

Error occurred in line :

> "log info c1.add(Calendar.Date,1);"
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property: info for class: Script16 error at line: 10

**Note : The current date should be any date in future and i want to increment by 1 day.**

Comment: please check the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing date object by hours/minutes in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166927/incrementing-date-object-by-hours-minutes-in-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TimeCategory` to add **the day** as shown below:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
  def tomorrow = new Date() + 1.day
  log.info tomorrow.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

**EDIT: based on OP comments**

Here is another away which is to add method dynamically, say `nextDay()` to `Date` class.

```
//Define the date format expected
def dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Date.metaClass.nextDay = {
   use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
      def nDay = delegate + 1.day
      nDay.format(dateFormat)
   }
}

//For any date
def dateString = '2017-12-14'
def date = Date.parse(dateFormat, dateString)
log.info date.nextDay()


//For current date
def date2 = new Date()
log.info date2.nextDay()
```

You may quickly the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/S2KXWD)</kbd>

Comment: This always gives me tomorrow date but i want whatever my date is, it should increment by 1 day. 'currentDate.next()' this works good.

Comment: @rAJ, That is so simple you see above right? Instead of `new Date()` pass any date and just do `+ 1.day` as given in the answer to get the next day.

Comment: @rAJ, you may find the `EDIT` section more helpful as that is using a method for easiness `nextDay`.

Comment: Another option: Date newDate = use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    previousDate + 1.day
}

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error you provide clearly tells you, that you have a syntax error. It says that there is no property `info`.

This is because you write

```
log info c1.add(Calendar.Date,1);
```

instead of

```
log.info c1.add(Calendar.Date,1);
```

If you would have used the correct syntax, it would complain that `Calendar` has no property `Date`.

So instead of

```
c1.add(Calendar.Date, 1)
```

you meant

```
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
```

But in Groovy you can even make it easier, using

```
c1 = c1.next()
```

Comment: Checked when fresh date start. It displayed colon sign at the end. e.g : '2017-12-1:'